# How do I validate a user not hacking the GPS position in an app?

Tags: android, gps, anti-cheat

I want to develop a GPS-based game (actually *part* of my game will be GPS-based, but the user will need to be authenticated).

In my back-end, I have entry points for the users collecting the data, so no data will be stored in the client app (at least not game data).

Assume I use a secure communications channel (say: HTTPS or WSS respectively), and the certificates are trusted (say, Startcom SSL... actually doesn't matter as I could focus on SSL providers later). This means: The client application connects to a server and receives its PubKey certificate.

Part of the communication (either by HTTPS, WSS, or regular sockets with TLS layer) will involve the client application send its GPS coordinates. They are sensitive data which will be stored in the server, but the data will be generated by the client.

**Q**: What technique (or perhaps an already-built-in application available on each Android device since a specific version) could I use to validate that the connecting application is the allowed one?

The problem I want to solve is this: I don't want a player cheating (by using a hacked client application respecting the same protocol of my application) sending a fake/crafted GPS position.

Technologies I will use: (Mainly) Android (perhaps later with other devices but not yet) 4+.

What do I expect: I don't need specific lines of code to solve the problem (althought lines of code are welcome), but focus in a good technique, concept, or complementary tool.

**Note**: This is not an account authentication problem. It is not about the ability of users to impersonate other users, but a hacked/cheatful client application impersonating a good client application (often by the same user trying to cheat).

Answer (score 1):

there is no way to validate real GPS location in android devices.

Comment: How do applications like Ingress face this issue?

Comment: if you search "ingress fake location" on google you find that this app cannot validate real location .

Comment: Seems you're right :(. Althought what I found regarding Ingress hacking was about spoofing the GPS device location (without considering the chance of using a hacked version of the app).